# Reference Page Filter in DAX expression - powerbi

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a report with a date snapshot filter on the report. I am writing a measure to calculate the sum of balances for the accounts that were opened that month. I would like to write the expression to the measure, which should look something like this:

```
CALCULATE(SUM([Table_Name]Balance_Amount), datesbetween([Table_Name]Account_Open_Date,"Beging_of_month","End_of_month").
```

I would like to reference the month from the snapshot date in the page filter.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You will get more and better answers if you take a bit of care in what and how you ask questions.  Here is a link to some help on how to ask good questions:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. In your request above, could you tell us exactly what question you wanted answered?

Comment: I would like to be able to reference the selected snapshot in the formula, and I would like to get the values of the beginning of the month and the end of the month, or any other way to filter to the accounts that were opened in the selected date from the snapshot date.

Comment: was that clear?

Comment: Could be good to provide your data model and a dataset to move forward on your request

Comment: Origination_Amount loan_Open_Date Process_Date
30582.54         8/22/2019 0:00 8/31/2019
15000   8/27/2019 0:00 8/31/2019
6720.7   8/22/2019 0:00 8/31/2019
6720.7   8/22/2019 0:00 8/31/2019
33300   8/27/2019 0:00 8/31/2019
5000   8/29/2019 0:00 8/31/2019
20495.37          8/6/2019 0:00        8/31/2019
11000   8/23/2019 0:00 8/31/2019
20000   8/14/2019 0:00 8/31/2019
45190   8/1/2019 0:00         8/31/2019
19000   8/8/2019 0:00         8/31/2019
17917.91          8/29/2019 0:00 8/31/2019
50000   8/30/2019 0:00 8/31/2019
25000   8/21/2019 0:00 8/31/2019

Comment: do you need more information?